# Unicode is not displaying Greek characters

Tags: java, unicode

I'm new to java programming and for our second assignment we were asked to make a chart showing Greek characters and their English equivalents.
When I enter them, for example `System.out.println ("\u0391")` a question mark is displayed when i run the program.
How do I fix this?

Comment: On what OS / console?

Comment: The Windows console doesn't support Unicode by default

Comment: The `System.out` encoding is often broken for historical reasons. On Windows the default encoding is obsolete and doesn't match the console encoding (which is even more obsolete.) Yes, it's a mess. There are no solutions independent of the operating system and console.

Comment: A learning assignment asking you to output Unicode to the console is deeply cruel! Could you output to a file or a web page instead?

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that your use of unicode is wrong, but that the output device you are using (maybe windows console) isn't capable to display the characters.

Try running it in an IDE, after making sure you configure it to use a font that contains greek letters.

Or write the list to a file and open it in some reasonable texteditor (even word should work)

Answer (score 0):

What your problem?

If u put:

```
System.out.println("\u0391 A");
System.out.println("\u0392 B");
```

you will get... you want to make an list to compare? is it?